# MYSQL nested inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, inner-join

I wanted to create a nested query that on the outside gets the title and price from a table called 'Books' while having a nest inside the query that gets the Author's First and last name for that specific book. I'm just a little confused on the Inner Joins and where they need to be placed. This is as close as I was able to get with it but this just prints every author for every book.

```
select Title, AuthorFirst, AuthorLast,Price from Book
JOIN
(select AuthorLast,AuthorFirst from Author 
INNER JOIN Wrote on Author.AuthorNum = Wrote.AuthorNum 
INNER JOIN Book on Wrote.BookCode = Book.BookCode group by title desc)Auth;
```

This joins the tables that I need but it prints every author in the DB with every book in the database. I think it has something with my Inner Joins not being specific enough.

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use a nested query ? Looks like you don’t need that to achieve your goal

Answer (score 1):

The `group by` clause is wrong and you should remove it. Once you do that, there's no need to nest the `join`s - you could just have several joins in the same query:

```
SELECT     Title, AuthorFirst, AuthorLast, Price
FROM       Book
INNER JOIN Wrote ON Author.AuthorNum = Wrote.AuthorNum 
INNER JOIN Book ON Wrote.BookCode = Book.BookCode
```

Comment: It is required that I nest unfortunately or else I would already have this done